# Connecting Ubuntu and windows via ethernet for file sharing

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet, smb

I am trying to set up shares between my Ubuntu laptop and my windows 11 laptop

I have a ethernet cable connected to Ubuntu, then going to a Netgear f2726 switch, I have also the windows 11 laptop connected to the switch.

On Ubuntu i set the connection setting to "share with others" On windows i have it set using DHCP so that IP addresses are automatically assigned.

Both IPss for the ethernet adapters on each machine now share a 169.254 address.

Ive done this exact set up before using windows 10, but now on windows 11 i cant set the network profile to private because it does not even give me the option. On the windows 11 computer in shows the connection as "unrecognized network"

how can i set up a share so that i can easily share files across this wired network.

I have drive c: set to shared on windows and i can intitiate the connection on windows but return an "invalid argument" error

how can i get windows to recognize the network, and how do i begin sharing files using this set up.

I am usign a wired connection with a switch because I plan to have another machine connected to the switch to use a file server / storage.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Windows has SMB and so you should be able to (from Ubuntu), net use T: //ipofwindows/folder and share files that way. I use this and it works for me